# Is strftime with nanoseconds possible in bash?

Tags: bash, unix, posix, strftime

Is there any way to obtain Unix Time with nanoseconds with strftime in bash?

My line for unix time :

```
<command> |  awk '{ print strftime("%s"),  $0; }'
```

I cannot use date +%N because date is only evaluated once.

Is there any work around?

Comment: Under *GNU/Linux* and [tag:bash] V>=4.2, you could use `proc/timerlist` in **pure bash**, see sample [elap.bash on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110859/1765658) and his [source file](http://www.f-hauri.ch/vrac/cours_truc-et-astuces_2012-04-03/elap.bash)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a workaround using while read. date gets updated that way. No need for strftime.

```
<command> |  while read line; do d=`date +%s%N`; echo $d $line; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could still use `date`

```
ls | xargs -IQ date "+%s.%N Q"
```

Just do not have % in your output... (but you can work around that too)

Comment: I don't think `xargs` is a good solution for long running commands. According to the man page: "When you use the -I option, each line read from the input is buffered internally." In practice, this means that `xargs` will not execute `date` until the entire command is finished. So if you are trying to timestamp the output of a daemon or long running command, `xargs` won't be of much help. I suppose you could work around this by not using `-I` and having `xargs` execute a wrapper around `date`, but that is a whole lot of hassle for an otherwise simple task in bash.