# Print elapsed time in secs with three trailing digits

Tags: bash

For a framework I'm writing I would like to measure how much a piece of (bash) code takes to execute and then print the elapsed time in seconds.

For measuring, I do the following:

```
start=$(date +%s%N)

# do something here

elapsed_time=$(($(date +%s%N) - start))
```

This gives me the elapsed seconds concatenated with the elapsed nanos. If I now divide this by 1000000, I'll get the time in ms

```
elapsed_time_in_ms=$(($elapsed time / 1000000))
```

This is all nice and seems to work but the real problem is that I want to print it in this format:

```
12.789s
```

where before the `.` are the seconds and after the dot are last 3 digits of the ms value.

How would I achieve something like that?

**EDIT**

I am aware that the time would probably not of much use, still I would like to implement this (even if only for cosmetic reasons :-)).

**EDIT 2**

For anyone facing the same problem:

In the end I've chosen to use time as it doesn't require a fork and seems to be the most portable solution.

Have a look at the `it` function and the global `total_elapsed_time` variable [here](https://github.com/helpermethod/bash-specs/blob/master/src/bash-specs.sh) to see how I implemented this.

Comment: Maybe you could use "time command" ?

Comment: `time` is a very good option here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `bc` command:

```
elapsed_time_in_ms=$(echo "scale=3;$elapsed_time/1000000" | bc)
```

The `scale` basically sets the number of digits you want after the `.`

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using shell parameter expansion or via `printf`.  For example, running the following two sequences one after the other printed out `1349883230.715` and `1349883230.721` in one run, and `1349884003.025` and `1349884003.032` in another.  (The `%N` date format fills with leading zeroes.)

```
  s=$(date +%s.%N); s=${s%??????}; echo $s
  t=$(printf "%20.3f" $(date +%s.%N)); echo $t
```

As mentioned in man bash under *Pattern Matching*, special pattern character `?` matches any single character.  As mentioned under *Parameter Expansion*, the form 
`${parameter%word}`
removes a matching suffix pattern: “If the pattern matches a trailing portion ... the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the "%" case) or the longest matching pattern (the "%%" case) deleted.”

Answer (score 1):

Just cut the digits after the first three off from the nanoseconds.

printf "%d.%.3ss\n" `date +%S` `date +%N` # It might not be terribly unwise to run date only once, btw.

-- print a digit followed by a dot, then treat the next argument as a string and print only the first three characters.

```
$ i=0; while [ $i -lt 9 ];do i=$((i+1)); sleep 0.1;   \
       printf "%d.%.3ss\n" `date +%S` `date +%N` ;done 
33.917s
34.025s
34.133s
34.240s
34.348s
34.457s
34.566s
34.674s
34.784s
```

Comment: This would not work if the `elapsed_time` would be something like 1.<whatever> or 100.<whatever>.

Comment: You control the variable. Where is the problem? Besides, it's trivial to separate what's before the dot from what's after. Anyway, the bc solution it more readable, just use that.

Answer (score 1):

As using `bc` implie forks which take time, I prefer this **pure bash** solution:

```
start=$(date +%s%N);sleep 1.1;elapsed_time=$(($(date +%s%N) - start))
_Z9=000000000
[ ${#elapsed_time} -lt 9 ] && \
    elapsed_time=${_Z9:0:9-${#elapsed_time}}$elapsed_time;
printf "%.3fs\n" ${elapsed_time:0:${#elapsed_time}-9
     }.${elapsed_time:${#elapsed_time}-9}
```

print:

```
1.107s
```

For that kind of things, I've wrote a little [*bash source file*](http://www.f-hauri.ch/vrac/cours_truc-et-astuces_2012-04-03/elap.bash) that will do
the job **quickly**.

It use on Linux `/proc/timer_list`, or on Linux `/proc/uptime` or `date +%s%n` not well tested on other systems (feed-back would be welcome ;).

It use two counters (one for each invocation and the other as an overall counter) and accept some arguments (read comments):

```
. elap.bash
elap -R ; for i in {1..10};do sleep .1; elap Counter $i;done;elap -t total
 0.110488478 Counter 1
 0.111014783 Counter 2
 0.117158015 Counter 3
 0.112897232 Counter 4
 0.111928207 Counter 5
 0.108822248 Counter 6
 0.113464053 Counter 7
 0.117487421 Counter 8
 0.115716626 Counter 9
 0.110493433 Counter 10
 0.008513430      1.137983926 total
```

And, as `bc` could be useful:

```
time echo 'scale=1000;pi=4*a(1);0'|bc -l 
0

real    0m1.590s
user    0m0.768s
sys     0m0.008s
```

or

```
elap -R;elap BC answer is: $(echo 'scale=1000;pi=4*a(1);0'|bc -l )
    1.539957483 BC answer is: 0
```

Using this script with `/proc/timer_list` could do:

```
elap -R ; for i in {1..10};do elap Counter $i;done;elap -t total
 0.001299574 Counter 1
 0.001574097 Counter 2
 0.005771637 Counter 3
 0.001428803 Counter 4
 0.010423721 Counter 5
 0.004037965 Counter 6
 0.001392464 Counter 7
 0.008092812 Counter 8
 0.001634280 Counter 9
 0.001365652 Counter 10
 0.008201473      0.045222478 total
```

While same script *whithout access to /proc*, using fork to `date +%s%N` give:

```
elap -R ; for i in {1..10};do elap Counter $i;done;elap -t total
 0.012148259 Counter 1
 0.013415551 Counter 2
 0.008279329 Counter 3
 0.013700332 Counter 4
 0.012837796 Counter 5
 0.015562929 Counter 6
 0.008062369 Counter 7
 0.016810494 Counter 8
 0.011537439 Counter 9
 0.009731194 Counter 10
 0.012959840      0.135045532 total
```

Where we could see that *fork have a cost* (near 1/100th sec in this case).

Well, finally, for **matching exact format for SO question** this little script could be patched, for sample in this way:

```
eval "$(sed -e < elap.bash '
    /6d/{ s/6d.%/10.3f/g;p;N;
        :a;
          s/^.*\n//g;N;s/" \\\n[ \t]*"/./; p;
          s/^.*//g; N;/elaP_elap2/ba; }')"

elap -R ; for i in {1..10};do elap Counter $i;done;elap -t total
     0.001s Counter 1
     0.006s Counter 2
     0.007s Counter 3
     0.004s Counter 4
     0.003s Counter 5
     0.002s Counter 6
     0.001s Counter 7
     0.001s Counter 8
     0.006s Counter 9
     0.002s Counter 10
     0.004s      0.038s total
```

38s total