# Unix process' CPU usage

Tags: bash, unix, cpu

I need to determeni the unix process' CPU usage... So, i want to write a bash script which will enable timer, run some process, stop timer. And I must know how that process used the CPU. And then compare with another process - which of them uses CPU less. Tried [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process?rq=1), but is uses c++, I would like to do that in bash. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the information in `/proc`, per http://stackoverflow.com/a/16736599/2908724?

Comment: It looks like this is exactly what you're asking for: http://serverfault.com/questions/73250/how-do-i-log-cpu-usage-per-process

Answer (score 7):

You want to "enable timer, run some process, stop timer."  Bash provides a builtin command to time processes, conveniently called `time`.  To find, for example, how long it takes the `date` command to run:

```
$ time date
Mon Dec 30 12:16:22 PST 2013

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

The first line of output above is the result of the `date` command.  The last three are from `time` telling you how long the `date` command took to run (real) and the CPU time spent in user mode and system mode.

`time` will optionally also display the CPU usage which is computed as the sum of user and system time divided by real time. With the following environment variable TIMEFORMAT, we obtain output that looks like the default except for the addition of one line showing CPU usage in percent:

```
$ TIMEFORMAT=$'\nreal\t%3lR\nuser\t%3lU\nsys\t%3lS\nCPU\t%P%%'
$ time sleep 1

real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
CPU     0.00%
```

The string is in the `$'...'` format so that `\n` is interpreted as a newline and `\t` as a tab.  If one does not want newlines and tabs, then `$'...' would not be needed.  For example, the following would produce the same information but on one line:

```
TIMEFORMAT='real=%R  user=%U sys=%S CPU=%P%%'
```

In the above TIMEFORMAT specifications, `%P` provides the CPU usage in percent.  For illustration, I also simplified the last spec above by dropping the "3" and "l" options; as a result time is displayed in default precision and in seconds rather than the longer minutes and seconds form.  See the description of the `TIMEFORMAT` environment variable in `man bash` for more information.

Comment: Under *GNU/Linux* and [tag:bash] V>=4.2, you could use `proc/timerlist` in **pure bash**, see [elap.bash on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110859/1765658) and his [source file](http://www.f-hauri.ch/vrac/cours_truc-et-astuces_2012-04-03/elap.bash)

Comment: John, you mean TIMEFORMAT='%P' and then time ./myprocess.sh ? And I will get the % usage of CPU by my process ?

Comment: @Volodymyr Yes.  Also, I just updated the answer with an example of `%P` usage that produces nicely formatted output.

Comment: @John1024, why sometimes my process takes 20% of the CPU and sometimes 40% ?

Comment: @Volodymyr The total (user+system) time can vary widely depending on what happens to be in the cache when you execute.  Separately, the CPU percentage will change depending on what other processes are competing for time and what their relative priorities are.